# Conflicting gradle tasks from different plugins

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have two plugins. maven and com.android.library

i want to run gradle install (to use maven install goal)

but when i do that, gradle executes the android install task.

how can i tell gradle to run the task from maven plugin instead?

thanks

Comment: Do you like to use Maven or Gradle ?

Comment: im using android studio so i want to use gradle.

i want each of the modules to be in a separate project so they take their dependencies from my local maven repository

any idea how?